# Schreibt man „gutes Neues Jahr!“ oder „gutes neues Jahr!“?

Tags: adjective, capitalization

Manche Leute schreiben zum Beispiel

> Ich wünsche dir ein gutes Neues Jahr!

obwohl *neu* hier als Adjektiv kleingeschrieben werden müsste. Ist *Neues Jahr* eine eigene Form? Oder handelt es sich einfach um einen Fehler?

Comment: Wenn klein, dann sicherlich mit Komma: `gutes, neues Jahr!”?`

Comment: Nein, ohne Komma ist korrekt (http://www.duden.de/sprachratgeber/komma-zwischen-adjektiven). Man wünscht ja nicht "ein gutes Jahr und ein neues Jahr".

Comment: also, ich persönlich wünsche ein *frohes Neues* und einen *guten Rutsch*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Es handelt sich zwar um einen festen Begriff, jedoch schreibt man bei diesen gemäss [Duden Regel 89](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/Gro%C3%9F-%20und%20Kleinschreibung#K89) das Adjektiv in der Regel klein.

Folglich wäre deine Schreibweise falsch.
Richtig wäre:

> Ich wünsche dir ein gutes neues Jahr.

Answer (score 8):

Auch wenn die [Dudenregel 89](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/3409/23) explizit das *"neue Jahr"* als festen Begriff aufführt, in dem das Adjektiv nicht großgeschrieben wird, muss man der Frage nachgehen, ob es sich hier nicht doch um ein besonderes **Kalenderereignis** oder mehr noch einen **idiomatisierten Gesamtbegriff** handelt, der nach derselben Dudenregel (2.c oder 3.) mit einem großgeschriebenen Adjektiv gebildet werden kann.

Die Großschreibung von *"neu"* findet nämlich durchaus Anwendung, wie man an diesem [Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gutes%20neues%20Jahr,gutes%20Neues%20Jahr&year_start=1920&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3)

[image]

sehen kann. Auch diverse Wörterbücher führen die Großschreibung an:

- [Woxikon](http://rechtschreibung.woxikon.de/schreibweise/gutes%20neues%20jahr.php)
- [Leo](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=neues%20jahr)

In redigierten Werken findet man die Großschreibung aber nur selten:

> *Natürlich war das Dreikönigstreffen der FDP, der erste Parteiauftritt im **Neuen Jahr**, immer dazu da, Parolen unter die Leute zu bringen und gleichzeitig anzudeuten, um welche politischen Schwerpunkte es gehen wird.*<sup>[Die Zeit 12.05.2009](http://www.zeit.de/online/2007/02/FDP)</sup>

Die Unsicherheit kommt auch daher, da es stehende Begriffe wie den "*Heiligen Abend"* oder das *"Fleißige Lieschen"* gibt, die vom Sprachgefühl her ähnlich gehandhabt werden wie das *"neue Jahr"* aber bei denen das Adjektiv großgeschrieben wird. Dies ist auch im Englischen  "*New Year"* so.

Man sollte also eine Großschreibung von "*neu*" nicht generell als *"falsch"* betrachten. Die Dudenregel zusammen mit der wesentlich häufigeren Kleinschreibung von "*neu"* sprechen aber dafür, dass dies die "richtige" oder zumindest die empfohlene Schreibweise ist.

Answer (score -1):

Falls du nicht ganz sicher bist oder etwas anderes wählen möchtest, kannst du auch "gutes Neujahr" schreiben. :-)

Comment: Neujahr ist an sich nur der erste Tag des neuen Jahres, es wäre also nicht wirklich passend.

Comment: Klar, ist das aber nicht im Grunde die eigentliche Frage? So hatte ich wegen des Zeitpunkts gedacht. Na ja. :-)